# The function 'IOSInitializationSettings()' isnt defined

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

Error is in IOSInitializationSettings is not define getting error in macOS

import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

```
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

Future<void> initNotifications() async {
  print('initNotifications() called');

  var initSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
  var initSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings();
  var initSettings =
      InitializationSettings(android: initSettingsAndroid, iOS: initSettingsIOS);

  notificationsPlugin.initialize(initSettings);
}

Future<void> showNotification(int notificationId, int messageCount) async {
  print('Displaying notification $notificationId...');

  var androidSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    "chat",
    "Chat Notifications",
    importance: Importance.defaultImportance,
    priority: Priority.defaultPriority,
    icon: 'app_icon',
  );
  var iOSSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
  var platformSpecifics = NotificationDetails(android: androidSpecifics, iOS: iOSSpecifics);

  await notificationsPlugin.show(
    notificationId,
    'New messages!',
    'You have $messageCount unread people chats in Marc Jr',
    platformSpecifics,
  );
}
```

Comment: Depends on the package version, if you are using above v10, `IOSInitializationSettings` is renamed to `DarwinInitializationSettings`.